# Wordpress Multisite: Images moved to /sites/1?

Tags: images, multisite, uploads, post-thumbnails, thumbnails

I noticed that my older images are no longer getting resolved by Wordpress 5.3.4. - the file doesn't exist on that path and 404 gets returned.

For images that were originally uploaded to

`https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/myimage-300x300.jpg`

Wordpress now looks here

`https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/1/myimage-300x300.jpg`

The function I'm using to resolve image path (none works with old images):

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/
`<img class="full-size" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($row['ID'], "medium"); ?>">`

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/
`<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' ); ?>`

I'm using Wordpress Multisite for several years already and never had this problem. Before, the older images of the used to be directly in `wp-content/uploads/` directory.

The change could either be part of a Wordpress update or a side effect of the newly installed Elementor plugin.

How to overcome this change?

[image: WP-Uploads]

Comment: I think the default blog in the network uses the path without /sites/1/ etc. - have you changed the default blog in your network? [Here's the code that adds /sites/](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.4.2/wp-includes/functions.php#L2363), guarded by `! is_main_site()`.

Comment: @Rup Not in the recent weeks and the problem started just recently, last thing I did was adding Elementor plugin. Here is my wp-config `define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 2);`. Both site 1 and 2 are having this issue (old images not resolved).

Comment: @Rup you had the right answer. somehow the default blog got switched from site 1 to 2, so site 2 is now at the root of the directory. last time i changed that value was months ago, it’s strange that image loading worked until now.